# Not able to cd while using SSH pipeline sshCommand in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline

In my jenkins scripted pipeline, one stage I am running is a bash script in remote machine. I tried few ways as follows but not coping with the following requirement :

- Since I  wanted to remote login to the server and then run few commands to deploy on the same. I am not able to `cd` using SSH Pipeline

So I want to use sshCommand to run a `cd` command on remote server and execute a script. What happens is that except cd command all other shell commands are getting executed.

```
  stage("CONFIGURE ENV") {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', passwordVariable: 'Password', usernameVariable: 'Username')]) {
        remote.user = Username
        remote.password = Password
        sshCommand remote: remote, command: "cd /abc/set/"
        sshCommand remote: remote, command: "pwd"
        sshScript remote: remote, script: "env.sh"
```

Error message I keep on getting while running the build:

[image]

Comment: Please include error messages as text. Don't use pictures of text.

Comment: Try providing the path to `env.sh` in the method argument instead.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiline syntax for the `command` argument.

Try this to get `cd` working as expected

```
sshCommand remote: remote, command: """
    cd /abc/set/
    pwd
"""
```

The current directory is reset with each invocation of `sshCommand` because it is a new shell. I'm not sure about the `sshScript` though. You may consider changing your script file to be included with these operations in the multiline syntax.